# WooCommerce - Move Product Description out Tabs into Summary

Tags: woocommerce

I've hunted high and low how to move the Product Description on a Single Product page of Woocommerce out of the tabs and in to the main section. I just can't find it anywhere!

If anybody can help me out it would be massively appreciated as i'm losing my mind a bit!

Thanks
Dan

Edit:

Just after submitting this I had an idea, all of the hooks are just functions so I created a new function and included the product description code:

```
function woocommerce_template_product_description() {
   woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
 }

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_product_description', 20 );
```

I'm not sure how perfect a method that is but it does the job I need it to do!

Comment: Hi, could you please, instead of editing the answer into your question, add an own answer, which you might accept.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just after submitting this I had an idea, all of the hooks are just functions so I created a new function and included the product description code:

```
function woocommerce_template_product_description() {
woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_product_description', 20 );
```

Edit:
since latest versions of woocommerce this code should still work like so

```
function woocommerce_template_product_description() {
wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_product_description', 20 );`
```

Comment: For anyone looking at this answer it's still valid and works great.However, the woocommerce_get_template function is being deprecated and replaced by wc_get_template so I'd suggest you use that.

Comment: It's possible to do this to additional information tab?

Comment: Not working anymore. Does anyone knows how to make this work with WordPress 4.2+ and WooCommerce 2.5.5+?

Comment: @JonathanSoifer replace `woocommerce_get_template` with `wc_get_template` in the answer's code.

Comment: since the description field is equal to the content field in Wordpress you can get the output by simple.    echo the_content(); instead of loading the wc_get_template

Comment: This doesn't work as intended. I just tested it and it shows description on two places. I adds one more description into summary. Why is this accepted as answer?

Answer (score 13):

This worked great, thanks for the solution to my problem!

To get rid of the tabs, use this code -

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );

function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

  unset( $tabs['description'] );        // Remove the description tab
  unset( $tabs['reviews'] );            // Remove the reviews tab
  // unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );      // Remove the additional information tab

  return $tabs;

}
```

Comment: Actually, if you wanna get rid of the tabs completely, merely do `$tabs = []` within that function. No need to target each node individually. It will, of course, disable any tabs added by plugins in the future.