# How can review be moved below product description in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My question is very similar to this [WooCommerce - Move Product Description out Tabs into Summary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19620974/1331135)

In my case, I want to move reviews tab and bring it below product description.

How can this be done using hooks? Is there a way to do this using some file within /template folder which can be overridden in child theme?

Answer (score 2):

After removing the reviews from the tabs using WooCommerce functions you can do something like this.

`add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', create_function( '$args', 'call_user_func(\'comments_template\');'), 14);`

Cheers

Comment: This seems to break when paginated.