# How to move Woocommerce Description tab below review tab

Tags: php, css, wordpress, tabs, woocommerce

I am trying to do the same thing than in here:

[How can review be moved below product description in woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948649/how-can-review-be-moved-below-product-description-in-woocommerce)

Only difference is that I want to move description tab. I've tried to change parameters in example below but I didn't managed to handle it.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', create_function( '$args', 'call_user_func(\'comments_template\');'), 14);
```

---

Alternatively, I was trying to move tabs to the top so description tab would be full width (I need it because I'm using big tables see: https://chemiq.sk/produkt/test/).

I've tried to do it with css

```
.woocommerce-tabs .panel {margin-left: 0px}
```

because I'm not familiar with creating new hooks, however it was not working. No change afterwards on live website at all.

Both of solutions would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I managed it with following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woocommerce_product_description_tab', 14 );
```